# How to unite two 3d matrices to result in a 3d matrice of 2d matrices of the same shape?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a 3d matrix of 2d matrices. But they arent all the same size.
Their 2nd dimension increments in with every sample.
So I want to fill NaNs above each of these rows, to make them all the same shape.

These are the samples:

```
# generated by this:
arr = np.asarray(df)
result = list((map(lambda i: arr[:i], range(1,df.shape[0]+1))))

[                                                                                  
   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71  ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91   ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21   ],   

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41   ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21    ], 

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11    ], 

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    ],

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     ],   

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     
   2019-06-17 08:54:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.11      12503.11  ]
                                                                               ]
```

expected result:

```
[ 
   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN                                                                 
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71  ],  

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN     
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91   ],  

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN    
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21   ],   

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41   ],  

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21    ], 

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11    ], 

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN 
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    ],

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
                   NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN  
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    ],  

   [               NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN   
   2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     ],   

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     
   2019-06-17 08:54:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.11      12503.11  ]
                                                                               ]
```

What is an efficient way to do this? (the data is about 100.000-500.000 samples long)

- is there a way to do this batchwise?
  (first 10% of the samples, then appending to list, the next 10%...
  In this case the ideal length of each sample is the one of the last sample in the batch)

EDIT:
Otherwise, is there maybe a way to generate 'result' and the expected outcome at once?
Like creating a second Dataframe full of NaNs? something like this? (pseudo:)

```
result = list((map(lambda i: nanarr[:j-i]+arr[:i], range(1,df.shape[0]+1))))
```

Comment: Please provide a proper mcve. Use small examples that are easy to visualize. Not only will it make your question more clear, but constructing such an example will help you understand the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume `result` is as you pasted above.

If `result` is a list of lists, you can modify result to get the output you asked for above using:

```
import numpy as np
longest_length = max(len(item) for item in result)
new_result = []
for L in result:
    new_result.append([np.NaN] * (longest_length - len(L)) + L)
```

This is about as "efficient" as you can get without using compiled code.

The problem you've asked itself is very inefficient. The output you are constructing has `N**2 * M` values, where N is how many samples you have, and M is the number of values in each sample. The output in this problem contains a lot of duplicated data. If you need a solution that is more efficient, you may try to find a way to write your code which does not have this duplication.

Comment: I guess the memory inefficiency, couldnt be avoided that much, but i guess the timeinefficiency is the bigger problem... Otherwise: Is there a way timeefficient way to generate "result" already with that the NaNs in it by a dataframe (which doesnt contain these NaN-rows?